# Ristrict method call to inherit class

Tags: c#, class

I have 2 classes, `Child` class inherits from `Parent` class.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string item{get;set;}
}

public class Child : Parent
{
}

public static void ConsoleWrite(Parent pitem)
{
    Console.Write(pitem.item);
}

public static void Main()
{
    ConsoleWrite(new Child(){item = "foo"});
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yPriNl

The `ConsoleWrite` method should only be able to be called with a `Parent` object but it can also be called with a `Child` object. Is there a way to ristrict that?

Comment: Why inheritance if you want to prevent it? The child has all capabilities of the parent, so it can also write on a console

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you just have to remove the inheritance from Parent to Child. This is likely not what you want, in which case, no, it is not possible. This is the basic rules of OOP. You've said that every child is also a parent, thus they can be used anywhere a parent is expected.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to prevent it only for one method which is only made for `Parent` objects and doesn't make sense to be called with inherit objects

Comment: But every Child is also a Parent. That's what `Child : Parent` means.

Comment: You can add if like this to function `if(!(pitem is Child))` and do your code only if it is not Child

Comment: A reason not to do this: `Parent c = new Child()` works. You pass c around your code, and you get to a point where you think it's a Parent, but it isn't. You call this method expecting an action, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Toshi: even if you have already accepted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44279683/284240), i had another idea, you could use a common interface instead (if possible)

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general that doesn't make much sense, why you use inheritance at all if you don't want that children can be used in methods that expect their parents?

You could prevent it at runtime by throwing an exception:

```
public static void ConsoleWrite(Parent pitem)
{
    if(pitem?.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Parent)) == true)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Only parent type is allowed", nameof(pitem));
    }

    Console.Write(pitem?.item);
}
```

---

Maybe you don't want inheritance but that both classes have common properties, you can let them implement the same interface:

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Item { get; set; }
}

public class Type1: IItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
}

public class Type2 : IItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

Now they aren't parent-children so a method that expects `Type1` can't be used with an instance of `Type2`. But if the method accepts `IItem` you'll have the same problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to organize your parent an child classe in a different namespace then your Program class. The define the child class as private. This way there would be no access to Child elemnts but only if they are casted to parents:

```
namespace ClassesDemo
{
   public class Parent
   {
       public string item{get;set;}
   }

   private class Child : Parent
   {
   }
}

namespace MainProgram
{
   class Program
   {
      public static void ConsoleWrite(Parent pitem)
      {
          Console.Write(pitem.item);
      }

      public static void Main()
      {
          ConsoleWrite(new Child(){item = "foo"});
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit to restrict it, however it does not show any compile time errors. Throws a run time error. Code below:

```
using System;


public class Program
{
 public class Parent
 {

    public virtual string item{get;set;}
 }

 public class Child : Parent
 {

    public new string item
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

}

public static void ConsoleWrite(Parent pitem)
{
    Console.Write(pitem.item);
}

public static void Main()
{
    ConsoleWrite(new Child(){item = "foo"});
}
```

}